# Device Id for push notification getting null sometimes using gcm in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have gone through the `googlecloudmessaging` code [on the google developer site](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html) and found the code

```
String SENDER_ID = "My-Sender-ID";
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
String registrationId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
```

Also put this code in the async task. Still if my net is slow than I am not getting the device id due to timeout through register method.

Is there any other way in which I can get the device id in some override method like `on registered`?

Comment: Where are you getting the sender id? It should look something like `12345678901` Are you doing it asynchronously?

Comment: sender ID?.........ARE you passing a valid sender ID

Comment: Ya I am passing the appid that is taken by the project on google devloper console..

Comment: Most of the Time I get the device id..but sometimes when internet is slow at that time I am getting the null value..

Comment: if there is a network timeout, putting your code anywhere would not solved the problem.

Comment: So there is no alternative to get your device registered by any means with gcm?

Comment: You may follow another official document here: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html